# Flutter compare num with dynamic from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dynamic

I want to compare the App's version manually through Firebase Firestore. In Firestore, I have a collection(system) with a document(update) with a field: *newest_v_app = number 7*. I want to access this field on a page in my app and want to compare it to a number. If the number in firestore is higher than the number in the app, I want a bool to set to true.

The Code I tried (to explain what I mean):

*UpdatePage.dart*

```
class UpdatePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _UpdatePageState createState() => _UpdatePageState();
}

class _UpdatePageState extends State<UpdatePage> {

  bool update_available = false;

  num current_version = 7;
  dynamic newest_version_from_firebase = 7;

  Future<dynamic> _getUpdateAvailable() async {
    final DocumentReference document = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('system').doc('update');
    print('Success GetUpdate 1');
    await document.get().then<dynamic>((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async {
      setState(() {
        newest_version_from_firebase = snapshot.data;
      });
    });
    print('Success GetUpdate 2');
    compareUpdate(context);
    print('Success GetUpdate 3');
    testUpdateComparer();
  }

  void compareUpdate(BuildContext context) {
    if (newest_version_from_firebase > current_version) {
      setState(() {
        update_available = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        update_available = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void testUpdateComparer() {
    if (update_available == true) {
      print('Success AvailableBool');
    } else {
      print('No AvailableBool');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Success Init');
    _getUpdateAvailable();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return Scaffold(
    );
  }
}
```

*Console & Error:*

```
I/flutter (15814): Success Init
I/flutter (15814): Success GetUpdate 1
W/DynamiteModule(15814): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(15814): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(15814): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutter (15814): Success GetUpdate 2
I/flutter (15814): No AvailableBool
E/flutter (15814): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(213)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '>'
E/flutter (15814): Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic>? from Function 'data':.
E/flutter (15814): Tried calling: >(7)
E/flutter (15814): Found: >() => Map<String, dynamic>?
E/flutter (15814): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter (15814): #1      _UpdatePageState.compareUpdate (package:myapp/UpdatePage/UpdatePage.dart:44:38)
E/flutter (15814): #2      _UpdatePageState._getUpdateAvailable (package:myapp/UpdatePage/UpdatePage.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (15814): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15814): 


Flutter 2.3.0-17.0.pre.19 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision bcf05f4587 (4 months ago) • 2021-05-23 02:19:02 -0400
Engine • revision 8cd4cf0a67
Tools • Dart 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-143.0.dev)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

*Changed num to int*

```
late DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

int current_version = 7;
  int newest_version_from_firebase = 7;

void getUpdateAvailable() async {
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("system").doc("update").get() as DocumentSnapshot;
    snapshot = data as DocumentSnapshot;
    setState(() {
      newest_version_from_firebase = snapshot["newest_version"] as int;
    });
    print(newest_version_from_firebase.toString());
    compareUpdate(context);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `snapshot.data` returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` from firestore and you're trying to assign it to the variable `newest_version_from_firebase` that you're trying to use as a *number*, which is not possible.

`snaposhot.data` returns a `Document` in which your have your version number probably stored as a key value pair, like: `{"versionNumber": 7}`

to access it your should do, for example:

```
newest_version_from_firebase = snapshot.data["versionNumber"] as int;
```

Comment: _["versionNumber"]_ comes out as an Error: _The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'_ . The _as int; works_ .

Comment: could you print what`s inside snapshot.data for me?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know what you mean but I think you want to know this: `I/flutter ( 4307): Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic>? from Function 'data':.`

Comment: I wanted to know the actual content of the Map<String, dynamic> data